# Is there a cleaner way to validate imported data from a CSV file with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, csv, angular-ui-router

I am able to create a list of Person objects from a CSV file in my personController.js. I would like to do some basic validation on this list of objects, then showing the user which are persons are valid and which are invalid (maybe in a grid) before submitting them to the server for additional validations.

Currently, I do something like this:

```
app.controller('PersonController', ['$scope', '$log', '$modal', 'person', 'personValidation', 'refData', function ($scope, $log, $modal, personSvc, personValidationSvc, refDataSvc) {
        $scope.validateImportedPersons = function (data) {
            // data is a list of Persons
            $q.all([
                refDataSvc.getAreaCodes(),
                refDataSvc.getZipCodes()
                // possibly more reference data to retrieve
            ]).then(function(refData) {
                personSvc.validatePerson(refData, data);
            },
            function(error) {
                // TODO: throw some error
            });
        };
}]);
```

Is there a better way than to do a $q.all? I could move this to the UI-Router's resolve section but how do I structure the refData service so that I can retrieve the data like a regular list rather than a service? Would I have 2 sets of functions, one for promises that will populate variables in the service and return a promise and the other to return the variable?

Comment: you are not capturing the output of `refDataSvc` anywhere.

Comment: Well I can reference the results by doing refData[0] and refData[1]. My question is that since the reference data comes from the server, I make http requests which means that I will be returning promises. But how do I write my refData service to avoid using $q?